# Bash loop for multivariable to the same data

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am trying to create models using multiple variables using bash loop. I need to run several predictions using different r2 and p-value cutoff for the same data.  The r2 and value parameters are
 `cat parameters`

```
0.2 1
0.2 5e-1
0.2 5e-2
0.2 5e-4
0.2 5e-6
0.2 5e-8
0.4 1
0.4 5e-1
0.4 5e-2
0.4 5e-4
0.4 5e-6
0.4 5e-8
0.6 1
0.6 5e-1
0.6 5e-2
0.6 5e-4
0.6 5e-6
0.6 5e-8
0.8 1
0.8 5e-1
0.8 5e-2
0.8 5e-4
0.8 5e-6
0.8 5e-8
```

The bash loop script I am using `test.sh`

```
RSQ=$(cat parameters | awk '{print $1}')
PVAL=$(cat parameters | awk '{print $2}')
season=("spring summer fall winter")
for i in $season;
do
echo prediction_${i}_${RSQ}_${PVAL}
done
```

the present output is

```
prediction_spring_0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8_1 5e-1 5e-2 5e-4 5e-6 5e-8 1 5e-1 5e-2 5e-4 5e-6 5e-8 1 5e-1 5e-2 5e-4 5e-6 5e-8 1 5e-1 5e-2 5e-4 5e-6 5e-8
prediction_summer_0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8_1 5e-1 5e-2 5e-4 5e-6 5e-8 1 5e-1 5e-2 5e-4 5e-6 5e-8 1 5e-1 5e-2 5e-4 5e-6 5e-8 1 5e-1 5e-2 5e-4 5e-6 5e-8
prediction_fall_0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8_1 5e-1 5e-2 5e-4 5e-6 5e-8 1 5e-1 5e-2 5e-4 5e-6 5e-8 1 5e-1 5e-2 5e-4 5e-6 5e-8 1 5e-1 5e-2 5e-4 5e-6 5e-8
prediction_winter_0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8_1 5e-1 5e-2 5e-4 5e-6 5e-8 1 5e-1 5e-2 5e-4 5e-6 5e-8 1 5e-1 5e-2 5e-4 5e-6 5e-8 1 5e-1 5e-2 5e-4 5e-6 5e-8
```

The desired output is

```
prediction_spring_0.2_1
prediction_spring_0.2_5e-1
prediction_spring_0.2_5e-2
prediction_spring_0.2_5e-4
prediction_spring_0.2_5e-6
prediction_spring_0.2_5e-8
prediction_spring_0.4_1
.......
prediction_winter_0.2_1
prediction_winter_0.2_5e-1
prediction_winter_0.2_5e-2
prediction_winter_0.2_5e-4
prediction_winter_0.2_5e-6
prediction_winter_0.2_5e-8
prediction_winter_0.4_1
..........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample output is not complete enough.  I can imagine two solutions: 1) you intend every season to be paired with every RSQ value to be paired with every PVAL value; or, 2) you want the stated R/P pairs to be matched with the seasons.

Solution for #1:  you need to loop over the R & P lists

```
for i in $season; do
    for r in $RSQ; do
        for p in $PVAL; do
            echo prediction_${i}_${r}_${p}
        done
    done
done
```

Solution for #2: read the file line by line

```
for i in $season; do
    while read r p; do
        echo prediction_${i}_${r}_${p}
    done < parameters
done
```

Comment: @7 Reeds thanks for the answer. I think the first solution works best by a small change in the script. `RSQ=$(cat parameters | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq)
PVAL=$(cat parameters | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq) season=("spring summer fall winter")
` ... Thanks alot

Comment: the first script is giving 96 lines as expected whereas the second one is giving only 92 lines.. the format of output is same in both cases except the number of lines printing, ie some of the combinations are missing

Comment: hmm, they *should* have different output. the first should be rendering every combination of season times R times P = 4*24*24 = 2304.  the second should be printing 96 = seasons times lines in file = 4*24.  That's why I mentioned that your desired output was a little skimpy.  I couldn't tell if you wanted all combos or not.  Anyway, good luck

Comment: I really like the `while` loop one. But it is only giving 92 lines instead of 96... why its so?

Comment: I don't know.  On my machine it prints 96.